# Skype Tool CheckedListbox error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm coding a Skype Tool.
I'm trying to get it to be black listed so they can spam people they won't from a checked list box but I set up everything right that I know of and I receive this on skype. system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox+checkeditemcollection it spams to that instead of the selected people I've chosen? Here's the code:

```
    private void metroButton6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.ToString()) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(metroTextBox5.Text))
        {
        timer3.Start();
        }
    }

    private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        skype.SendMessage(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.ToString(), metroTextBox5.Text);
    }

    private void metroButton9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer3.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: Where are the errors?

Comment: `metroComboBox1.SelectedItem` returns `object` I think you meant, `metroComboBox1.SelectedItem.Text`, If you didn't inserted using `new Item(..)` than you can use `.ToString()` and then do your testing.

Comment: Is this windows forms or wpf? Please add the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SelectedItem` of ComboBox is always a `object` which cannot be compared with a string. that's  why you are getting such exception, so i suggest you to use:

```
metroComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToSting();
```

Hence your `if` will be like the following:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(metroComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(metroTextBox1.Text))
        {
          // code here 
        }
```

and the sending message will be like this:

```
skype.SendMessage(metroComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString, metroTextBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is `metroComboBox1.SelectedItem` is of type `object`. The method `string.IsNullOrEmpty` expects a `string` as parameter. So you can try this

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(metroComboBox1.SelectedItem as string) && ...
```

The `as` operator returns a `string` or `null` if `metroComboBox1.SelectedItem` is `null` or not a `string`.

But if `SelectedItem` is not a string you may rather use this:

```
if (!(metroComboBox1.SelectedItem == null || 
      string.IsNullOrEmpty(metroComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())) && ...
```